# Чат для приложения под android и ios

Tags: java, android, ios, highload

Разрабатываю приложение под андройд, ios и не могу решить сохранять ли сразу  сообщения в базе данных на стороне сервера  которые пользователи посылают друг другу(что очень затратно в плане ресурсов и времени) или использовать второй вариант, который используется в различных социальных сетях по типу вконтакте или instagram, а именно  доверить это дело клиентской части, чтобы приложение на стороне клиента сохраняла сообщения в файле или в памяти, а после закрытия приложения или завершения диалога между двумя клиентами отсылала все новые сообщения на сервер для их сохранения в базе данных. Я склоняюсь ко второму варианту, но я не знаю насколько такой метод надежный, что нужно учитывать при таком варианте? Есть ли идеи как получше организовать онлайн чат между двумя клиентами?

Comment: "а именно доверить это дело клиентской части, чтобы приложение на стороне клиента сохраняла сообщения в файле или в памяти, а после закрытия приложения или завершения диалога между двумя клиентами отсылала все новые сообщения на сервер для их сохранения в базе данных" Там такого нет.

Comment: Suvitruf, почему же когда заходишь оффлайн в приложение то откуда он берет список сообщений?

Comment: Он кеширует их локально. На сервер оно отправляет срахзу.

Comment: то есть он одновременно и кэширует на стороне клиента  и сохраняется на стороне сервера

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше хранить на стороне сервера и на стороне клиента, в таком случае Вы сможете синхронизировать сообщения между устройствами.

Comment: объясните в чем состоит эта синхронизация?

Comment: Если у вас сообщения будут храниться на сервере, при заходе с другого устройства они подтянуться с сервера. Если будут храниться только на телефоне, так сделать уже не получится.